# Drupal 7 and CSS - How to have a default style for links without affecting other css styles?

Tags: theming

I'm theming a Drupal 7 website using Bootstrap and a sub theme that I have put together. I have used CSS to design some of the menus. For this I have included code in the overrides file so as not to hack the original Bootstrap file.

Here's an excerpt from the CSS file to customize the look of a menu.

`#block-menu-office li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-right: 20px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-style: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-right: 0.1em;
  padding-top: 0.1em;
}`

This works well.

Now I want to customize how links on the website look like. For some reason they seem to be black with no underline. I want them blue with an underline.

When I add this code, the links do turn blue and show up with an underline. However the menu items also get underlined.

`a:link {
    color: red;
}`

How do I alter the default appearance of the links without affecting how the menu items look? I added a class to the CSS and used this class in the CKEditor when adding the link to the node. However this seems tedious. I would prefer to have a default appearance or alternatively a default class assigned to each link within the node when it is being created. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, I would expect that the styling of menu links by Bootstrap would be [more specific](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) than the (general) CSS rules you provide for styling links. But a workaround would be to reapply the styling on the menu links in your sub-theme ([with more specific CSS rules](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)).

Comment: That's a very useful link. Unfortunately I'm not able to apply it here. I don't know CSS. What I have done is changed the value in the Bootstrap variables file to this: `@link-color:            blue;`  That seems to have solved it for now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

put your general code first... and add a: link to your menu rule... CSS Cascades... and  the more specific you are naming your element the fewer things it touches

Comment: I understand. One of these days I will try and learn CSS. Thanks.